# How do I create simplistic window-like elements in a command-line program?

Tags: command-line, c++, text, ncurses

When I execute `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` in the terminal I see a simplistic window-like listmenu. Is there an way to make something like that in C++?

This looks something like:
[image]

Comment: This is about programming, it is OT for Ask Ubuntu. Technically it belongs on [so] but it will be removed from there for lack of research - include what you have tried when you re ask it there.

Comment: @Tim I don't agree this is off-topic here. It's asking how to implement something that appears in a highly distro-specific context. (If this had to be done from scratch each time--it doesn't--and answers had to give lots and lots of code, this might be a bad fit here.) I think an answer should mainly say what library provides the menu interface seen when using `dpkg-reconfigure` and how to install that library, link against it, and view its documentation on Ubuntu (which would be on-topic even without the mention of `dpkg-reconfigure`). I'm writing an answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text-based window-like interface, contained within a terminal, that you see when you run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` is coded using [the *ncurses* library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). So if you want your program to provide an interface that looks like that, you can use ncurses too.

- Here's the [ncurses project page](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).
- Here's an [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).
- You can install [some ncurses documentation files](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/ncurses-doc/filelist) with the [ncurses-doc [image: Install ncurses-doc]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ncurses-doc) package.

  This includes the ncurses manpage, which you can also [view online here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man3/ncurses.3ncurses.html). It also includes manual pages for all the functions provided by the ncurses library (some share a manpage). Those manpages are *not* currently online at [manpages.ubuntu.com](http://manpages.ubuntu.com).

To build software using ncurses in Ubuntu, you should get the appropriate [header files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive) package. Unless you're cross-compiling, this will be:

- For programs using traditional strings where most characters are represented by a single byte (for example, [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)), use [libncurses5 [image: Install libncurses5]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libncurses5).

  This is probably what you want if your strings are arrays of `char` (in C and other C-based languages) or `std::string` (in C++).
- For programs requiring wide character support, use [libncursesw5 [image: Install libncursesw5]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libncursesw5).

  You'll especially need this if your strings are arrays of `wchar_t` (in C and other C-based languages) or `std::wstring`, `std::u16string`, or `std::u32string` (in C++).

Optionally, for help debugging your program, you might *also* want debug symbols (for debuggers such as [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). For that, install [libncurses5-dbg [image: Install libncurses5-dbg]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libncurses5-dbg) or [libncursesw5-dbg [image: Install libncursesw5-dbg]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libncursesw5-dbg) too.

See also [the ncurses in Ubuntu page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ncurses), which contains a list of the major ncurses packages in Ubuntu as well as version information for each currently supported Ubuntu release.

When you build your program with GCC (e.g., with the `gcc` or `g++` commands), give it the argument `-lncurses` or `-lncursesw`, usually at the very end of the command. This links your program to the ncurses library. For example:

```
g++ -Wall -g -o hello hello.cpp -lncurses
```

That compiles *hello.cpp* to produce an executable with debug symbols (`-g`), called *hello* (`-o hello`), warning on most things you might want a warning about (`-Wall`), and linking to the regular (not wide character) ncurses library (`-lncurses`).